# Is there a way to get non-technical users to send me an iPhone device ID?

Tags: iphone

I am currently testing my iPhone app with some different users. So far, though, I can only test with users that I meet in person and connect their iPhone to my Macbook Air and get a device ID by using Xcode.

Not being an Apple user myself, I'm not sure if Xcode is the only way to get a device ID, or if it is installed on most Macbooks, or what.

I have users who have asked to be included in my testing phase, but they live around the world so I can't reasonably go meet them even if I wanted. Also, some users have iPhones, but not Macs.

So, is there a simple, end-user-friendly way they can find out their device ID and send it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the device id in itunes:

1. Launch iTunes and connect your iPhone.
2. In the right pane, locate the information about your iPhone, including its name, capacity, software version, serial number, and phone number.
3. click on Serial Number.

See [this post](http://www.innerfence.com/howto/find-iphone-unique-device-identifier-udid) for more details and pictures.